# WebViewClient onReceivedError IF() DOES NOT WORK

Tags: java

I have this code where it does not work:

```
if (desctiption == "net :: ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT" ")
```

instead if I write

```
if (desctiption! =" Net :: ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT "")
```

I create the Toast object and the text is equal to

```
net: : ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

The code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            if (description == "net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT"){
            toast.show();}



        }


    });
}
```

Comment: You might try replacing the `description == str` with `description.equals(str)`.  A `==` comparison compares references to your strings, where .equals compares the values of the strings.

Comment: description.equals(str). A =="net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT" ?

Comment: String str ="net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT";

Comment: if (description.equals(str)){
                toast.show();}  It works perfectly. you are great

Comment: `"net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT".equalsIgnoreCase(description)`